# Can't open .cab file

Tags: sharepoint, windows-10, cab, wsp

I have a SharePoint Template that was created by a different developer I don't have the VS Solution for it. I downloaded it as .wsp file but I couldn't view it which made me change it to .cab I received the "can't open file" error. To solve it I used Easy 7-zip to extract it and the error was "can't open the file as [Cab] archive Is not archive.I also tried Start -> Run. then: msconfig.exe I couldn't "Expand File..." at tab General. I just want to read everything in the Template before even editing it, I know that would be a bigger issue. Any help or ideas are appreciated thank you.

Comment: Open folder where is that wsp file. In windows explorer click View tab and check "File name extensions". Then select file and change wsp to cab. You can open that cab file in 7zip.

Comment: @MarkoTica I am currently trying to follow these steps https://bindtuning.com/resources/blog/how-to-manually-edit-a-sharepoint-wsp-file   but on step 2 it says "unsupported archive type" on the sec step. thank you

Comment: Did you try with IZArc or 7zip? Maybe  Easy 7-zip can't open cab file? I'm using 7-zip and it's working fine for unpacking. For packing you can use MAKECAB.exe or  that IZArc.

Comment: @MarkoTica with the 7zip if I try to Extract I get an error: can't open the file as cab archive, is not archive. And if i try to archive it, it says "can't open file" I am close to giving up.